# $\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{-2xy}{x^2-y^2}\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation, but I can't seem to get the variables separated on each side.$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{-2xy}{x^2-y^2}\right)$$

Can you help?

Comment: Substitute $ u =\frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit, thanks, I tried that but I got stuck. I will try again.

Comment: You equation is homogeneous of order 2.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $y=u x$ gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dy}{dx} =u + x \frac{du}{dx} =\frac{2u}{u^2-1} \\
\frac{du}{dx} =\frac{3u-u^3}{u^2-1} \\
\frac{u^2-1}{u(3-u^2)} = \frac{2u}{3(3-u^2)} - \frac{1}{3u}
\end{eqnarray*}
Should be easy to complete from here ?

Comment: I am an idiot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: to never have this question again, note that if 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=f\bigg(\frac{y}{x}\bigg)
$$
i.e. a function in which the transformation $x\mapsto ax$ and $y\mapsto ay$ is not seen by the function, the transformation 
$$
vx=y
$$
to get the separable equation
$$
f(v)=\frac{dv}{dx}x+v
$$

Comment: oooh this downvote is curious